Общее количество кадров в FFmpeg
Как получить общее количество кадров в видео, через FFmpeg?

Пакет FFmpeg содержит кроме самой программы ffmpeg тоже программу ffprobe, которую вы можете использовать для вашей цели:
ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_frames test.mp4

(Вместо test.mp4 будет, конечно, имя вашего файла.)

Вывод:
Вывод будет долгим, но в конце него вы увидите что-то такое:

[STREAM]
nb_frames=17225
[/STREAM]



Объяснение:

v:0 значит первый видео стрим,
-show_entries stream=nb_frames значит, что вас интересует количество кадров.


Примечание:
Когда вы хотите, чтобы на выводе было только количество кадров, вы можете в предыдущую команду ffprobe добавить (еще перед именем файла)
-v error -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1

чтобы запретить вывод всего остального.
